# Why is git blind to new commits in a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've made a new commit inside a submodule but git doesn't indicate the submodule is changed (new commits) on the root level of the repository.

`git status` says everything's up-to-date and doesn't indicate a change in the submodule (e.g. new commits).

`git commit --allow-empty` didn't help either.

Comment: You need to push the commit to the origin. Only commit but not pushing is a local operation, so the maybe the parent module does not realize of the pointer change. I would also try to fetch all the modules involved...

Comment: If you add/remove commits in your submodule you should see a SHA update in the parent repo. Pushing is not necessary. What do you get from `git submodule status`?

Answer (score 0):

A submodule is nothing more than another Git repository, plus some linkage that gets stored in the superproject.

One Git repository is, in general, *never* aware of commits in some other Git repository.  One might think that the linkage in the superproject could make the superproject Git more aware ... and sometimes, it *can* be, but not in your case.  (We don't know exactly what your case is, but obviously, whatever your case is, it was not one of these rare ones where the superproject notices right away. )

If one Git repository—let's call it **S** for Submodule—is a *clone* of some other Git repository (let's call it **OS** for Origin of Submodule), then you can enter repository **S** and run `git fetch origin`.  This brings any new commits from **OS** into **S**.  No new commit gets *checked out* in **S**, because `git fetch` never changes anything except remote-tracking names in  a repository.  It only picks up new commits (then updates **S**'s `orgin/master` and so on as approrpriate).

If you now, in repository **S**, run `git checkout hash-id` or `git checkout non-branch-name`, the commit you specified is checked out in **S** as a detached HEAD.  If you run `git checkout branch-name`, the commit you specified is checked out as an attached HEAD: **S** is now on a branch.  The important part of all of this is not whether HEAD is attached or detached.  It is that you checked out some specific *commit*.<sup>1</sup>

When some Git repository—let's call it **R**—is using some other repository **S** as a submodule, various operations in **R** will enter submodule **S** and run `git checkout hash`, to put **S** in a detached HEAD state on one particular commit.  The hash ID to use here is recorded in commits made in **R**.

If you yourself enter **S** and `git checkout` some *other* hash ID, then return to **R** and ask about its (**R**'s) status, the Git handling **R** will notice that **S** is no longer on the commit that **R** requested.  It will therefore say that something has happened in **S**.  You can now run `git add path/to/S` to update the hash ID in **R**'s index, so that it records the hash ID of the commit you selected in **S**.  Making a new commit in **R** at this point will record that new hash ID as the correct hash ID.

Checking out any particular commit in **R** will fill **R**'s Git's index with the submodule hash ID from that commit.  Unless you specify a recursive checkout, this won't affect the hash ID that is checked-out as a detached head in **S**; you must run `git submodule update` to make **R** enter **S** and issue the appropriate `git checkout hash` command.

If you want to do your own manual control of **S**, this is the right way to do things: you don't want **R** checking things out in **S** and messing with your manual control.  If you *don't* want manual control—if you want **R** to always control **S**—use the `--recursive` checkout mode in **R**.

---

<sup>1</sup>Although **R** normally *uses* a detached head, superproject **R** *does not care* whether **S**'s HEAD is attached.  **R** is going to record a raw commit hash ID, no matter what.  So it just reads the hash ID from **S**, not the branch-name-or-lack-thereof.